# Understanding delaying or advancing a discrete time signal

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have a discrete time signal x[n]. It is said that x[n-k], where K>0, is a delayed version of x[n]. I am trying to understand this intuitively. My observation is in the signal I am subtracting time in x[n-k], by k units. Means I am doing some thing 'quickly' as compared to x[n]. So why do we call it delay instead advance?

Comment: If you let $y_n = x_{n-k}$, then the value of $y_n$ corresponds to the $x$ value at time $n-k$, which is before $n$ (assuming that $k>0$).

Answer (score 2):

I hope the given answer is not satisfactory since delay means shift rightwards on time scale. But according to the explanation it's appearing at left of the x[n] sample.
You just see like: n-k=0. i.e. n=k means the initiation time for signal. Practically you think the time when your class (for a student) starts as t=0 time and just assume you reached 10 minutes late. So it's 10 minutes delay on time scale. So for you the class initiation time (t=0) is t=10 or t-10=0. I hope so you understood the concept.

Answer (score 2):

This resource has some great depictions of a `time-advanced` signal (ie left-shifted) as well as a `time-delayed` signal (ie right-shifted).

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/basic-signal-operations-in-dsp-time-shifting-time-scaling-and-time-reversal/

The convention in signal processing appears to be inverted from the standard mathematical convention of 
`y(x) ==> y(x-k)` where `k > 0` is used for right shifting a general function. Apparently in the realm of signals (discrete or otherwise) the reality of being in the time-domain, of being time-domain entities, using positive offsets to denote time advancing behavior is more important. Under this convention a signal value happens *sooner/earlier* in time, and that takes precedence.

This makes some degree of mnemonical sense if you focus on **time** itself. Specifically with the delayed behavior adopting a negative value to delay or retard a signal, to push it out in time, to move further back in time. In this case think negative/decrease/slow-down, these all appear to be in near conceptual proximity of each other don't you agree?

Likewise in adopting a positive value to denote the advancing, or speeding up of a signal, for a signal value to happen faster/sooner.

The positive case on its own may be less clear than the negative case, since *speeding up* is ambiguous with respect to time compression where time is scaled/frequency increases. However it becomes very clear when paired alongside the negative case I think.

In a nutshell: positive advance, negative delay. Those appear to be the preferential conventions in signal processing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an advance. You are subtracting k units from n. So if you where just calculating $x[n]$, you will be $k$ units ahead of the calculation of $x[n-k]$.

If $k = 5, n = 10$: 
$$
\begin{align*}
&x[n] = x[10] \\
&x[n-k] = x[10-5] = x[5]
\end{align*}
$$

So the calculation for $x[n-k]$ lags $x[n]$ by $k = 5$ time units

Answer (score 0):

It's far more of a conventional thing than a logical thing. (similar to how it's said that electricity flows from positive to negative cause that's easier to imagine.)

If you think of time as a river that's constantly flowing, if you want to slow it down/ delay it, you'll have to **push it back** and resist the flow. And if you want to speed it up or advance it, you'll have to **push it forward** to speed up the flow.
So intuitively it makes sense to say to delay time you'll subtract, and to advance time you add. But in practice it's actually backwards, which get's a bit confusing when learning it.

Tldr: Conventionally it's - to delay and + to advance, cause it's easier to visualize it that way.